# Getting a negative prediction after min-max scaling the price in a linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, feature-scaling

I was trying to make my mean squared error cost lower by scaling the target feature, primarily because it reaches 1e10's in digit

I use this dataset from kaggle to calculate land price X = LT, Y = Harga https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wisnuanggara/daftar-harga-rumah

The code i used to input into numpy array:

```
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import numpy as np

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('DATA RUMAH.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

y_train_data = np.array([])
x_train_data = np.array([])

def get_x_train():
    x_train = np.array([])  # Initialize x_train as a local variable
    for x in range(2, 1011):
        data = ws.cell(row=x, column=5).value
        x_train = np.append(x_train, data)
    return x_train

def get_y_train():
    y_train = np.array([])  # Initialize y_train as a local variable
    for y in range(2, 1011):
        data = ws.cell(row=y, column=3).value
        y_train = np.append(y_train, data)
    return y_train
```

Linear regression & Gradient Descent Code:

```
import math, copy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from excltool import *
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

# Load our data set
x_train = get_x_train()#features
y_train = get_y_train()  #target value

mean = np.mean(y_train)
min = np.min(y_train)
max = np.max(y_train)
y_train = np.array([(i - min) / (max - min) for i in y_train])

#Function to calculate the cost
def compute_cost(x, y, w, b):
   
    m = x.shape[0] 
    cost = np.float64(0)
    
    for i in range(m):
        f_wb = (w * x[i] + b)
        cost = (cost + (f_wb - y[i])**2)
    total_cost = np.float64(1 / (2 * m) * cost)

    return total_cost

def compute_gradient(x, y, w, b): 
    """
    Computes the gradient for linear regression 
    Args:
      x (ndarray (m,)): Data, m examples 
      y (ndarray (m,)): target values
      w,b (scalar)    : model parameters  
    Returns
      dj_dw (scalar): The gradient of the cost w.r.t. the parameters w
      dj_db (scalar): The gradient of the cost w.r.t. the parameter b     
     """
    
    # Number of training examples
    m = x.shape[0]    
    dj_dw = np.float64(0)
    dj_db = np.float64(0)
    
    for i in range(m):  
        f_wb = (w * x[i] + b) 
        dj_dw_i = ((f_wb - y[i]) * x[i])
        dj_db_i = (f_wb - y[i]) 
        dj_db += (dj_db_i)
        dj_dw += (dj_dw_i) 
    dj_dw = dj_dw / m 
    dj_db = dj_db / m 
        
    return dj_dw, dj_db

def gradient_descent(x, y, w_in, b_in, alpha, num_iters, cost_function, gradient_function):
    """
    Performs gradient descent to fit w,b. Updates w,b by taking 
    num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha
    
    Args:
        x (ndarray (m,))  : Data, m examples 
        y (ndarray (m,))  : target values
        w_in,b_in (scalar): initial values of model parameters  
        alpha (float):     Learning rate
        num_iters (int):   number of iterations to run gradient descent
        cost_function:     function to call to produce cost
        gradient_function: function to call to produce gradient
      
    Returns:
        w (scalar): Updated value of parameter after running gradient descent
        b (scalar): Updated value of parameter after running gradient descent
        J_history (List): History of cost values
        p_history (list): History of parameters [w,b] 
    """
    
    # Specify data type as np.float64 for w, b
    w = np.float64(w_in)
    b = np.float64(b_in)
    
    # An array to store cost J and w's at each iteration primarily for graphing later
    J_history = []
    p_history = []
    
    for i in range(num_iters):
        # Calculate the gradient and update the parameters using gradient_function
        dj_dw, dj_db = gradient_function(x, y, w , b)     

        # Update Parameters using equation (3) above
        b = b - alpha * dj_db                            
        w = np.float64(w - alpha * dj_dw)                            

        # Save cost J at each iteration
        J_history.append(cost_function(x, y, w, b))
        p_history.append([w, b])

        # Print cost every at intervals 10 times or as many iterations if < 10
        if i % math.ceil(num_iters/100) == 0:
            print(f"Iteration {i:4}: Cost {J_history[-1]:0.2e} ",
                  f"dj_dw: {dj_dw: 0.3e}, dj_db: {dj_db: 0.3e}  ",
                  f"w: {w: 0.3e}, b: {b: 0.5e}")
 
    return w, b, J_history, p_history  # Return w and J,w history for graphing

# Initialize parameters with np.float64 data type
w_init = np.float64(0)
b_init = np.float64(0)

# Some gradient descent settings
iterations = 1000000
tmp_alpha = np.float64(1.0e-10)

# Run gradient descent
w_final, b_final, J_hist, p_hist = (gradient_descent(x_train, y_train, w_init, b_init, tmp_alpha,
                                                    iterations, compute_cost, compute_gradient))

# Print the result
print(f"(w, b) found by gradient descent: ({w_final}, {b_final})")
```

got the last result as:

```
Iteration 950000: Cost 2.24e-03  dj_dw: -9.486e-03, dj_db:  3.615e-03   w:  4.850e-04, b:  9.52354e-07
Iteration 960000: Cost 2.24e-03  dj_dw: -8.682e-03, dj_db:  3.617e-03   w:  4.850e-04, b:  9.48737e-07
Iteration 970000: Cost 2.24e-03  dj_dw: -7.946e-03, dj_db:  3.619e-03   w:  4.850e-04, b:  9.45119e-07
Iteration 980000: Cost 2.24e-03  dj_dw: -7.273e-03, dj_db:  3.621e-03   w:  4.850e-04, b:  9.41499e-07
Iteration 990000: Cost 2.24e-03  dj_dw: -6.657e-03, dj_db:  3.623e-03   w:  4.850e-04, b:  9.37877e-07
(w, b) found by gradient descent: (0.00048503387319465645, 9.34254408473887e-07)
```

descaled the y_train:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Assuming you have x_train, y_train (already scaled), w_final, and b_final

# Descale the y_train using the min-max scaling parameters (min and max)
min_y_train = np.min(y_train)
max_y_train = np.max(y_train)
y_train_descaled = y_train * (max - min) + min

# Compute the predicted values based on the descaled y_train
predictions = w_final * x_train + b_final

# Descale the predictions using the min-max scaling parameters (min and max)
predictions_descaled = predictions * (max - min) + min

# Plot the original x_train and descaled y_train
plt.scatter(x_train, y_train_descaled, label='Original Data')
# Plot the predicted values
plt.plot(x_train, predictions_descaled, color='red', label='Predicted Values')
plt.xlabel('x_train')
plt.ylabel('y_train')
plt.title('Descaled y_train vs. Predicted Values')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Predicted Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpD6V.png)

made my input prediction:

```
prediction = w_final*1 + b_final
prediction_descaled = prediction * (max - min) + min
print(prediction_descaled)
```

which result in -0.11096116854066342 where it shouldnt even be a minus, if it was not scaled everything works fine but my cost reaches 9e18, i wanted to make it lower so that i can better present it

i think i messed up in the descaling process

---

*EDIT:
i also tried scaling my x

```
mean = np.mean(x_train)
xmin = np.min(x_train)
xmax = np.max(x_train)
x_train = np.array([(i - xmin) / (xmax - xmin) for i in x_train])
```

and then plotted the descaled version of both:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Assuming you have x_train, y_train (already scaled), w_final, and b_final

# Descale the y_train using the min-max scaling parameters (min and max)
y_train_descaled = y_train * (ymax - ymin) + ymin
x_train_descaled = x_train * (xmax - xmin) + xmin

# Compute the predicted values based on the descaled y_train
predictions = w_final * x_train + b_final

# Descale the predictions using the min-max scaling parameters (min and max)
predictions_descaled = predictions * (ymax - ymin) + ymin

# Plot the original x_train and descaled y_train
plt.scatter(x_train_descaled, y_train_descaled, label='Original Data')
# Plot the predicted values
plt.plot(x_train_descaled, predictions_descaled, color='red', label='Predicted Values')
plt.xlabel('x_train')
plt.ylabel('y_train')
plt.title('Descaled y_train vs. Predicted Values')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Descaled_Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W716a.png)

and tried to input a prediction of my own x(1):

```
scaled_input = (1 - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)

prediction = w_final*scaled_input + b_final
prediction_descaled = prediction * (ymax - ymin) + ymin
print(prediction_descaled)
```

but got a result of 92720747 which is too big because the non-scaled code outputted a more reasonable 33047038

Comment: The learning rate is low (0.1 should work ok). The algorithm is fitting a line through the data, so it looks like it is converging well. You made a prediction on the value of x=1. In the dataset, the average value of x is about 250 . Try making a prediction on 250 (`scaled_input = (250 - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)`) - it should give a sensible value for y. The scaling looks right to me.

Comment: then what if i wanted to know how much the value of y per x?

Comment: The coefficient `w` tells you how much y per unit x. If you used `x_scaled` and `y_scaled`, then `w` will be scaled y per scaled x. To unscale `w` you could use a formula: `w_unscaled = [w_scaled * (y_range / x_range) * (1 - x_min)^2 + y_min * (1 - x_min)] / (1 - x_min)` (use with caution, I worked it out but it's untested).

Comment: An alternative way to get the unscaled `w_scaled` is similar to your initial method: (1) Set `x_unscaled = 1`. (2) Calculate `x_scaled = (x_unscaled - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)`. (3) Get `y_pred_scaled = w_scaled * x_scaled + b_scaled`. (4) Then `y_pred_unscaled = y_pred_scaled * (y_max - y_min) + y_min`. (5) Finally, `w_unscaled = y_pred_unscaled / x_unscaled` which is just `y_pred_scaled` since we intitially set `x_unscaled=1`. Note that `x_min`, `y_min`, `x_range`, `y_range` must be the same values that were used to scale the training data.

Comment: THANKYOUSOMUCHH i'll try to do your suggestion and inform you of my findings after

Comment: No problem. Correction to my previous comment: you need to repeat the process twice - once with `x_unscaled=1` and then again with `x_unscaled=0`. Then `w_unscaled` is the first `y_unscaled` *minus* the second `y_unscaled`.

Comment: hey i have a question, what do you mean by x_unscaled=0?

Comment: `x_unscaled` is the value of your input feature when no scaling is applied. You ultimately want to to find the unscaled `w`. Since you are first scaling `y` and scaling `x`, what that gives you is `scaled_w`. To get the unscaled `w` in this case, you need calculate `y_unscaled` twice - once where you set `x_unscaled=0`, and a second time where you set `x_unscaled=1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the plot you provided, it seems like any x value below ~220 will result in a y value below 0. The negative value you're getting matches with what the red line shows.

There may be an issue with scaling. You're scaling y, but not x. I think it's usually more important to scale x. Assuming x is a matrix of shape `samples x features`, then you can scale x as follows:

```py
#Scaling training features
# x_train.ptp() calculates x.max() - x.min()
x_train_scaled = (x_train - x_train.min(axis=0)) / x_train.ptp(axis=0)

#fit model using x_train_scaled...
```

This will scale all the columns (features) in one go. Then, when you want to make a prediction with a new x, scale the new x using the *training* x values:

```py
x_pred_scaled = (x_pred - x_train.min(axis=0)) / x_train.ptp(axis=0)

#y_pred = w X x_pred_scaled + intercept
```

What I described above is just for x. In the code you provided, you were scaling y as well, and the way you scaled/unscaled y looks correct.

If your cost is reaching 9e18 something may be going wrong, like almost dividing by zero. At the last iteration your cost was down to 2.24e-03 - please clarify where the 9e18 is from.

Comment: I got 9.29e+18 from my unscaled code, considering the y's scale that can reach up to 5e10 is it not permissable?

Comment: It could be fine. As long as your final cost is low, then it's probably ok.

Comment: i tried scaling x and y, is this the right way to make the prediction? (input is 1) 

scaled_input = 1 * (xmax - xmin) + xmin

prediction = w_final*scaled_input + b_final
prediction_descaled = prediction * (ymax - ymin) + ymin
print(prediction_descaled)

Comment: cause i got an exorbitant amount even tho i got the same line as before i descaled, i think i did something wrong

Comment: i edited my question and added my code of also scaling x, you can find it after the *EDIT part

Comment: I've added a comment under your edited question